# OSGI Service as Endpoint in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm wondering if it is possible to use a OSGI Service as endpoint in WSO2 ESB?
I read a lot of documentations and examples on wso2 site but couldn't find anything about it.
Mostly the endpoints were just web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways you can use OSGi Service as a Web Service.

For example, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-OSGi/index.html

I haven't tried this myself, but what I suggest is to expose your OSGi Service as a Web Service and then you use that as an endpoint in WSO2 ESB.

I hope this helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. OSGi services are visible only to the OSGi bundles which resides in an OSGi container. ESB endpoints can be a HTTP, JMS, VFS, FIX etc.